# IntelliJ crystal reports plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins, intellij-idea, crystal-reports

Does anyone know if the IntelliJ IDE has a plugin to view and edit crystal reports (.rpt files)? I know eclipse has a workable plugin but I cannot seem to find anything for IntelliJ.